# Why this static_assert not compile on MacOS? Strange typeid() issue

Tags: c++, macos, types, clang

I have code I try to compile on 64 bit MacOS with clang.

```
#include <cstdint>

int main(){
    static_assert(std::is_same<long, int64_t>::value, "");
}
```

I did some checks and both long and int64_t are signed integers and sizeof() reports they are 8 byte long.

Both types must be same type, however, when I check with typeid().name() gives result "l" for long and "x" for int64_t.

Whats going on here?

How to rewrite static_assert so it will be portable between 64 bit Linux and 64 bit MacOS?

---

## Update

I think the proposed duplicate is not answering my question.

I checked "stdint.h" on MacOS, and it mention 40, 48 and 56 bit integers too. I believe it is related to that, since pointer distance_type on the MacOS is "long".

Please reopen :)

Comment: Both types might be able to represent exactly the same range of integer, with the exact same representation, and still be different. The duplicate explains why `int64_t`is likely and alias of `long long` rather than `long` on your 64-bits machine. What exactly do you want to check with your `static_assert`?

Comment: static assert checks if two iterators have same difference_type. one is defined by me (int64_t), another is "char *" (long).

Comment: Why do you use a different type? Why not use [ptrdiff_t](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/ptrdiff_t)?

Comment: at some point it was a better idea to use uint64_t.

Comment: I did changed it, and I just check it is 8 bit. Thanks.